# How to handle Click event on a Control when a child control has been clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, click

I have a `UserControl` that has someother controls:

[image]

I need to enable click on any item I click of the user control so I can set the UserControl borderstyle.

This works if I don't have any control added, but If I have for example a panel and I try to click on the panel my UserControl's click event doesn't get fired.

This is my code:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Click += Item_Click;
        IsSelected = false;
    }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsSelected)
        {
            IsSelected = true;
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSelected = false;
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        }                
    }
}
```

Any clue on how to fire my UserControl click's event even if I click over other elements?

Comment: You must set the `Click` event of panel again

Comment: So there is no way to catch a click that is over the UserControl?

Comment: You can pass *all of controls that you want to handle these click* in constructor of your control and handle all click event. this is very easy method for your goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's really simple to achieve this, you can iterate through all the controls contained in your UserControl and register the `Item_Click` to their EventHandler which will invoke it when the Click event is fired:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl {
    public TestControl( ) {
        //...

        for ( int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++ ) {
            Controls[ i ].Click += Item_Click;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```